# validation not working when dynamically loading partial view through ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

i am stuck in a situation where i am not able to apply validation when the contents are loaded dynamically through jquery ajax call...

I found this solution everywhere but dont know how to use where to write this code??

```
$('form').removeData("validator");
$('form').removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
```

MY CODE is [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934304/jquery-accordion-validation-not-working-when-rendering-partial-view-through-aj/16936246?noredirect=1#comment24532571_16936246) in my previous Question

Comment: please somebody help yaar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do realise this is a old question. But it might be useful to someone who comes here in the future.

This is as simple as to run the above code after a successful ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: editPageUrl,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { id: taskId },
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        var taskBody = $('#task-body');
        $(taskBody).html(data);
        var $form = $(taskBody).find('form');
        $form.removeData("validator");
        $form.removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);
    }
});
```

When the ajax request finishes just reset the validation so it works. Doing that will add all the elements to jquery validation and trigger the validation on a submit on the form inside #taskeditform-body