# How do I validate multiple forms and use ajax to send email?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

[Fiddle so far](http://jsfiddle.net/6CsDe/)

I'm quite new to jquery and more so to jquery validation plugin. My problem is how to validate multiple forms (the user can add them dynamically) separately/uniquely? I already added different names to the forms, if that is any help?

My second problem is how to `$ajax();` to send emails without having to refresh the page.

I'm hoping for a detailed explanation of a solution so I can understand better. Thanks!

Comment: you need to have a server side component to send mail, link it to the ajax call.

Comment: well for validation you can go through http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation

Answer (score 0):

You have to `include script of validation plugin` or use [cdn](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js) Read http://jqueryvalidation.org/

```
$("form").each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : 'mail.php',// write code to send mail in mail.php
                data    : $(form).serialize(),
                cache   : false,
                dataType: 'text',
                success : function (serverResponse) { 
                      alert('mail sent successfully.'); 
                },
                error   : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      alert('error sending mail');
                }
            });
            return false; // Temporary
        }
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/FUxKP/)**

Comment: How do I validate each form separately? Also, I want to send an email to the user if the validation is a success. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: @user2772219 take a look on my demo first

Comment: It's the same as before? Also, whenever I add a new form, it will only validate the first form.

Comment: For this you can create an `single form` with `multiple form elements`, See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022224/jquery-validation-plugin-doesnt-validate-dynamically-created-form-elements