# Webform Validation in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller, webforms

I want to add some validation to my web form, the user inputs are created in a dynamic table**(user can add and delete rows)**, basically the user will click submit when they have completed, and i will call a java script function to build me a list to pass to my controller, my question is how i can validate the users inputs to ensure its right data type etc before the list is built

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <table class="tab-content" id="tab_logic" name="table1">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 25px">
                                #
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 150px">
                                Status
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 250px">
                                Actions
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 150px">
                                Target
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 100px">
                                Progress
                            </th>
                            <th class="text-center" style="width: 250px">
                                Comments
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody id="mainData">
                        <tr id='entry1'>
                            <td>
                                1
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <select name="select" class="form-control" id="status1">
                                        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select:</option>
                                        <option style="color: green; background-color: white">Competent</option>
                                        <option style="color: orange; background-color: white">Improvement-Required</option>
                                        <option style="color: red; background-color: white">Below Average</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id='action1'></textarea>    
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="date" class="form-control" id='target1'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id='progress1' required="required"/>

                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id='comments1'></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <div>
                <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-left">Add Row</a>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; <a id='delete_row' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Delete Row </a>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="button" value="Submit" id="subButton" widthvalue="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="vertical-align: bottom"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
  $("#subButton")
            .click(function() {

                for (var j = 1; j <= x; j++) {

                    var statusEntered = document.getElementById("status" + j).value;

                    var actionsEntered = document.getElementById("action" + j).value;

                    var targetEntered = document.getElementById("target" + j).value;

                    var progessEntered = document.getElementById("progress" + j).value;

                    var commentsEntered = document.getElementById("comments" + j).value;

                    var area = "PersonalDevelopment";

                    var test = employeeSelected.value; 

                    var entry = new newEntry(statusEntered,
                        actionsEntered,
                        targetEntered,
                        progessEntered,
                        commentsEntered,
                        area, test
                    );

                    arrayDetails.push(entry);  
                }

                    sendToController();
            });

        function sendToController() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Save", "OneToOne", "EmpList")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: JSON,
                data: JSON.stringify({ methodParam: arrayDetails }),
                traditional: true
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can use libraries like `jquery validator` or you can do manually before submitting the form

Comment: Have you any examples of this being done manually?

Comment: kindly check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386971/adding-jquery-validator-rules-to-dynamically-created-elements-in-asp#9399114

Comment: Here we have clear docs http://www.formvalidator.net/