# Validating dynamically added input elements for a child collection

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive-validation, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using Asp.Net Core MVC with unobtrusive validation. I have a form which allows dynamic addition of input elements for a child collection and I want to include these in client-side validation. I've seen some of the previous solutions for this e.g. [Adding jQuery validator rules to dynamically created elements in ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386971/adding-jquery-validator-rules-to-dynamically-created-elements-in-asp), but the client validation still doesn't take place.

Here is my code. First an html block is cloned and appended to a form list when a button is clicked.

```
<li class="newVideoRow well-sm">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="Videos.Index" value="#" />
        <label>Video Title:</label>
        <input name="Videos[#].VideoTitle" class="videoTitle form-control inline" placeholder="Enter a short title for this video" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Video Link:</label>
        <input name="Videos[#].VideoUri" type="url" class="videoUri form-control inline" value="http://" />
    </div>
</li>
```

The jQuery for the cloned list item elements then manipulates the [#] index adds validation attributes and presumably re-parses the unobtrusive validator.

```
        $('#addNewVideo').click(function(){
            var nr = $('.newVideoRow').clone();
            nr.removeClass('newVideoRow').addClass('videoRow');
            var index = (new Date).getTime();
            $(nr).find('div input').each(function(divIndex, divElement){
                $(divElement).attr('name', $(divElement).attr('name').replace('#', index));
                var inputName = $(divElement).attr('name');
                if ($(divElement).attr('type') != 'hidden'){
                    $(divElement).attr('data-val', 'true');
                    $(divElement).attr('data-val-required', 'A value is required');
                    $(divElement).after('<span asp-validation-for="' + inputName + '" data-valmsg-replace="true" class="text-danger field-validation-valid"></span>');

                    $('form').removeData('validator').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
                    //Parse the form again
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));
                }
                $(divElement).val($(divElement).val().replace('#', index));
            });
            $('#videoList').append(nr);
        });

        $('form').submit(function(e){
            saveSubmitValues(); // copies some other values to hidden fields
        });
```

If I leave the added inputs blank and submit, the html5 url-type input detects an error but the required VideoTitle field doesn't display an error. Can anyone detect where I am going wrong or suggest a solution?

Answer (score 7):

There are two reasons why it's not working.
1. You're using `asp-validation-for`, which is done server-side on tag helpers, instead of `data-valmsg-for`.
2. You need to call `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse()` **after** adding the cloned elements to the DOM.

Here's a working example with your code:
https://codepen.io/judowalker/pen/QgRybW

Comment: Little amendment- Both following lines should be added.

Comment: 1.  $("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");

Comment: 2. $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($("form"));